Docker swarm in windows server with Linux based containers
Hello I managed to run Linux based containers on windows server 2019 but I couldn't run them on docker swarm cluster using windows server host can someone help me with this issue !
I tried to enable LCOW in that windows server node but docker swarm still couldn't resolve the container OS
Giving the example of this docker nginx image :
docker pull nginx
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from library/nginx
Digest: sha256:0f04e4f646a3f14bf31d8bc8d885b6c951fdcf42589d06845f64d18aec6a3c4d
Status: Image is up to date for nginx:latest
docker.io/library/nginx:latest

I succeed to pull it in this windows server node
now this is my docker-compose file
version: '3.8'

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.50'
          memory: 512M
        reservations:
          cpus: '0.25'
          memory: 256M
    networks:
      - my_overlay_network
    ports:
      - "80:80"
networks:
  my_overlay_network:
    external: true

but here the docker service ls  shows me this error :
jqgw2tspmb5blhtj484tq83xq   test_nginx.1   nginx:latest@sha256:0f04e4f646a3f14bf31d8bc8d885b6c951fdcf42589d06845f64d18aec6a3c4d             Running         Pending 48 seconds ago   "no suitable node (unsupported platform on 1 node)"


Just run linux servers.

LCOW was an experimental feature for Windows Server and was discontinued. Running Linux containers on Windows Server directly is not supported. If you really want to run it on Windows Server, you need to run a Linux VM and operate from there. There's one alternative which is running WSL2, but keep in mind that this is all manual - your compose environment won't know WSL2 is a thing like in Docker Desktop on Windows client (10 and 11). Also, running Linux containers on WSL2 for Windows Server is for test and development purposes, not production. Here's the link to try out WSL2 on Windows Server: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/itops-talk-blog/using-wsl-2-on-windows-server-2022-to-run-linux-containers/ba-p/3624745

So as you said there is no solution to run a docker swarm on a windows server with Linux based containers even if I  activate LCOW !?

because i tried to run this command :
docker stack deploy -c Documents/docker-compose.yaml test --resolve-image=never
and now this error occurs :
[Event Detail: failed to configure network adapter a3023e0f-4e4e-47a4-b4ca-3da7a841e170: netlink.RouteAdd(netlink.Route{LinkIndex:5, ILinkIndex:0, Scope:0x0, NewDst:netlink.Destination(nil), Encap:netlink.Encap(nil)}) failed: file exists: exit status 255 Stack Trace:

It's weird that this error is related to configuring the networking. In any case, the Linux containers won't be able to run as we most likely removed components that will be missed when you try to run it.
